# What set(s) do these pieces belong to?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

The orange wheels are very similar to the red buggy from the Neptune carrier.

Comment: Please unaccept my answer, it is incorrect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most of this looks like it's part of the [Mars Mission](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=34.592) range - however, none of those sets contain [the 2 flames](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=85959pb01a&colorID=17&in=A), and the Minifig has both wrong colour torso (grey, instead of white), and the wrong type of helmet (he has [Headgear Helmet Space](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=193a2) instead of a [Motorcyle Helment](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2446&idColor=1#T=C&C=1))

As for *which* Mars Mission set you have there, from curved Windscreen, the Technic bars that the wheels are attached, the device the Alien is strapped into, and the arm on the drill, I believe that this is [ETX Alien Strike](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7693-1)

[image: Picture of set]

You can see the Alien in the holding contraption at the back of the mini rover, the wheels beneath it, the drill-arm in the centre, and the cockpit & windshield at the front.  It looks like you might actually have most of the rover in your photo!

Answer (score 6):

The set you are looking to identify is part of [Mars Mission](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=34.592) theme from 2008. The reason for that - sets from this theme are the only ones to use the wheels you describe in Orange color. However, it is not clear which size you got as there are several: [Small](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6118&colorID=4&in=A), [Large](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2515&colorID=4&in=A) and [Giant](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2573&colorID=4&in=A). Most of these sets (but not all) include the other pieces you've mentioned.

This is the best I could get you without pictures. This is true if the set you got is not a mix of parts from more than one set or mixture of sets.

Comment: Thanks it was indeed the ETX Alien Strike as I also have the black space ship.